# Talend - How to Run Subjobs based on certain condition

Tags: talend

i have encountered a issue where the requirement states that i have to run a query in Postgres to check if the Indicator is either Y or N. If the indicator is Y then i have to an ETL pipeline called SubJob1 and if the condition Turns Out to be N then i have to run ETL pipeline called SubJob2. I have tried using tjavaRow, tFlowtoIterate, etc for this without any success.

what i am trying to do

tpostgresqlinput(to check the condition) ---> tjavaRow(to check if its Y or N)

what is desired

1. check Postgres if the column is Y or N
2. If the column is Y then run Subjob1
3. If the column is N then run Subjob2

I really dont know how to achieve this at the moment. If anyone has any suggestions, i will be grateful. Please do let me knw if further information is required. Thank you.

Comment: Use an IF connector.

Answer (score 2):

Hi i think you should store your indicator into a globalVar then use it in a 'Run If' trigger.

So a job would look like somthing like this :

[image]

Your PG input that send directly to a tFLowToIterate you can also, use tJava, tSetGlobalVar, ... (I usually go with tFlowIterate in case multiple executions is needed) then use two 'Run If' that check your condition, in this case :

```
((String)globalMap.get("IND")).equals("Y")
```

For the first pipeline and :

```
((String)globalMap.get("IND")).equals("N")
```

For the second

Here is the configuration for the tFlowToIterate :
[image]

Comment: Nice answer but I believe that you should use `((String)globalMap.get("key")).equals("value")` instead of `((String)globalMap.get("key")) == "value"`

Comment: ah yes, I just wrote the answer quickly, but yes you are write I will edit the answer